# How to get index from key or key value pair in dart flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I have a list of key value pair

I want to search for the index from key like (get index in list where key == 0) and then from that Index I want to change the value.

or change the value to something where key == 1

```
void main() {
  var listAnswers = [];
  var keyPair = {
    'Key': 0,
    'value': false,
  };

  listAnswers.add(keyPair);

  keyPair = {
    'Key': 1,
    'value': 1,
  };

  listAnswers.add(keyPair);

  keyPair = {
    'Key': 2,
    'value': DateTime.now(),
  };

  listAnswers.add(keyPair);

  print(listAnswers);

  var index = listAnswers.getIndex('key', 0)
  // got the index 1 (where key = 0, and value = false)

  listAnswers[i].value = true; // then I want to do something like this.

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  var index = listAnswers.indexWhere((pair) => pair['Key'] == 0);
      print(index);
      
     listAnswers[index]['value'] = true;
```

Comment: Thanks. Merym you are genius :D

Comment: can you help me with this as well?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64029980/radiolisttile-inside-statefulbuilder-not-deselecting-other-options-inside-radiol

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `keyPair` like this

```
var keyPair = {
    'Key': 0,
    'value': false,
  };
```

Here `keyPair` is `Map`.

To access a key inside the map you have to use `keyPair['Key']`.

Now when you add this map into a list you have a list of maps.

To get the index of the map where the key is 0.

```
var index = listAnswers.indexWhere((map) => map['Key'] == 0);
```

Now to change the value at that index.

```
// listAnswers[index] returns a map
// to access the 'value' you need to use listAnswers[index]['value']
listAnswers[index]['value'] = true;
```

Comment: Thanks you both shared the same answer and it worked for me :)